# EF Architecture, adding inherited entity to an existing table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I´m not sure this could be achieved, therefore I would ask you guys!

Say I have an existing table which contains a book register with all books that was even written. We can call this table "Books" (entity), and it has BookID, BookTitle and BookDescription. I´m using EF and Database first approach, and working with the DbContext.

Very simple structure, but know I would like to sell books and want to take advantage of my existing Books table register that users can browse on my homepage. I also have some used books for sale that I want to connect to my Books table somehow.

In my world I would like a structure like a base class named "Book", and derived classes "NewBook" and "UsedBook", but i`m totally lost how i can achieve this with my existing Books table and with Entity Framework.

Comment: Does a `NewBook` has different properties than a `UsedBook`? If not, you can add an Enum or even a bit field to determine wether the book is new or user.

Comment: Yes, there are a few props more on the usedbook, eg. place, telephone. The only way i can think of is to make a join between books and usedbook, then I've got all fields for the usedbook (book+usedbook) entity.

Comment: I also want to get a clean entity of my Book, without NewBook or UsedBook involved.

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: [Table Per Hierarchy Inheritance](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96185/Table-Per-Hierarchy-Inheritance-in-Entity-Framewor)

Comment: @Henk Mollema Yes, The Table Per Hierarchy (TPH) Inheritance approach is the best solution for this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to implement inheritance in EF in a project and I found it difficult to do when creating the subclasses as tables in the database first. Instead, I added the subclasses as entities in the EF model, generated the database script, and then ran the script to add the tables to the database. Here are the steps I took:

1. In the EF model diagram .edmx file right click the background and Add New... Entity.
2. Type in the entity name (in your example UsedBook) and select the base type as Book.
3. After clicking OK you can then add properties to UsedBook.
4. Right click the background again and select Generate Database From Model. This will generate a SQL file.
5. Now if you have data in your existing database you DO NOT want to execute the entire script as it will drop your existing tables. Instead, find all references of the new table UsedBook (will be called Books_UsedBook in the database) and just execute those lines. You may need to manually change the reference to the Book table as it may have pluralized incorrectly. Just make sure the Book table name in the script matches what's in your database.
6. After executing the script, go back to your .edmx model, right click the background, and select Validate. You shouldn't have any errors here.
7. In your database you will now have a class Books_UsedBook with the BookId column referencing the BookId column in the Books table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Are you explaining the TPH inheritance?

Comment: I did actually end up with TPH. It´s now so abvious :)